# TooltipDialog inside DropDownButton not working for custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip

Used example from https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DropDownButton">
  <span>Register</span>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TooltipDialog">
     <label for="name">Name:</label> <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" id="name" name="name"><br>
     <label for="hobby">Hobby:</label> <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" id="hobby" name="hobby"><br>
     <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And put it into custom widget. On click an error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

Error occurs only for my custom widget. Using code snipped on other pages works fine.

Comment: Can you share your custom widget code ? The problem is most likely inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that custom widget was overwriting `startup()` function without `this.inherited(arguments)`.

Looks like some `DropDownButton` magic was heppening there..